# How to log @Entity changes with @EntityListeners?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a logger that logs any CRUD operations on an entity. It is easy on `insert` or `delete`. But how can I access the previous entity during `update` process, so I could log the changed fields (eg access via reflection).

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
}

public class AuditEntityListener {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private static final Marker AUDIT = MarkerFactory.getMarker("AUDIT");

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Object target) {
        log("new object inserted", target);
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(Object target) {
        log("entity deleted", target);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Object target) {
        //TODO how can I access the "old" entity, so that I can log only changed fields (eg via reflection)?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the previousState in a PostLoad method and check the differences in PreUpdate Method

```
// EDIT
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
   @Transient
   private transient MyEntity savedState;

}

public class AuditEntityListener {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private static final Marker AUDIT = MarkerFactory.getMarker("AUDIT");

@PostLoad
 private void saveState(MyEntity target){

    target.savedState = SerializationUtils.clone(target);
 }

@PrePersist
public void prePersist(MyEntity target) {
    log("new object inserted", target);
}

@PreRemove
public void preRemove(MyEntity target) {
    log("entity deleted", target);
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate(MyEntity target) {
    MyEntity previousState = target.getSavedState();
}
```

}

Comment: That would be nice, **but** how can I access the transient saved state from within `AuditEntityListener`? (because certainly I would not want to pollute every of my domain classes with postload + logging stuff.

Comment: The postload method can be in the AuditEntityListener as well as In the Entity
You can access it through the parameter of the PostLoad, PreUpdate or any other 
public class MyEntityListener {
@PreUpdate
  void onPreUpdate(MyEntity myEntity) {
      System.out.println("MyEntityListener.onPreUpdate(): " + myEntity);
  }
}

Comment: At the end I created a parent `abstract` class that provides access to the persisted state. So any entity extending it will get the state saved through `AuditEntityListener` `@PostLoad` method calling the setter, likewise calling the getter in `@PreUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Hibernate's Event SPI. Hibernate Envers implements some of the SPIs provided. I am currently using Hibernate 5.

Implement the `org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEventListener` interface, which will let override `public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event)`. `PostUpdateEvent` lets you access some useful stuff e.g. `PostUpdateEvent#getOldState()`.

Once you've done that you need to register that listener to an SPI integrator. Implement `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`.

```
// Overriden public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
//                          SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, YourListener.INSTANCE);
```

Then register that integrator in your application by creating the `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` . Inside this file, you need to put the class name for your implemented Hibernate Integrator. Example:

```
com.company.my.ImplementedHibernateIntegrator
```

Other versions of Hibernate may have a different approach, e.g. https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/

Comment: Isn't `evers` for keeping a domain history inside a database table? I' only looking for a simple the logging mechanism, not for history persistence...

Comment: @membersound yup. We also didn't need Envers, so we only implemented HIbernate's Event SPI and got some ideas from Envers.